# Sphinx 2.3 to Sphinx 3.1 conversion

Tags: indexing, sphinx

I have a data source configuration file for sphinx which has the following code

```
source src1_c_march_april_2020
{
        type                    = mysql

        sql_host                = 67.225.224.103
        sql_user                = enspekto_wrdp3
        sql_pass                = xxxxxxx
        sql_db                  = enspekto_wrdp3
        sql_port                = 3306  # optional, default is 33
        sql_query_pre           = SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=utf8
        sql_query_pre           = SET NAMES utf8

        sql_query_range = SELECT MIN(wpf7_readibility_content_index.tw_scrap_data_id)+10921149,MAX(wpf7_readibility_content_index.tw_scrap_data_id)-632561+631300 FROM wpf7_readibility_content_index
        sql_range_step = 100000
        sql_query                =  SELECT wpf7_readibility_content_index.id,wpf7_readibility_content_index.tw_scrap_data_id, wpf7_readibility_content_index.content,TABLE1.id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP( TABLE1.sql_date ) AS added_ts \
        FROM wpf7_readibility_content_index \
        INNER JOIN TABLE1 ON TABLE1.id = wpf7_readibility_content_index.tw_scrap_data_id WHERE wpf7_readibility_content_index.tw_scrap_data_id >=$start AND wpf7_readibility_content_index.tw_scrap_data_id <=$end

        sql_attr_uint           = tw_scrap_data_id
        sql_field_string        = content
        sql_attr_timestamp      = added_ts

}

index test1_march_april_2020
{
        source                  = src1_c_march_april_2020
        path                    = /home2/spindexes/test1_march_april_2020
        html_strip              = 1
        html_remove_elements    = style, script, object, embed, span
        expand_keywords         = 1
        blend_chars             = +,&->:#
        # inplace_enable          = 1
        # charset_type            = utf-8

}


indexer
{
    mem_limit       = 1024M
        max_iosize              = 1048576
        max_iops                = 40
        write_buffer            = 2M

}
searchd
{
        listen                  = 9312
        listen                  = 9306:mysql41
        log                     = /var/log/sphinx/searchd.log
        query_log               = /var/log/sphinx/query.log
        read_timeout            = 5
        max_children            = 30
        pid_file                = /var/run/sphinx/searchd.pid
        seamless_rotate         = 1
        preopen_indexes         = 1
        unlink_old              = 1
        workers                 = threads # for RT to work
        binlog_path             = /home2/spindexes/
}
common
{
        lemmatizer_base         = /usr/local/share/sphinx/dicts/
}
```

This configuration file was made using sphinx 2.3 rules. I want to convert the script according to sphinx 3.1. What changes will be needed for this conversion?

I visited http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/sphinx3.html#sphinx-3 for reference but there they are using the following sample

```
index rt
{
    type = rt

    rt_field = title
    rt_field = content

    rt_attr_uint = gid # regular attribute
    rt_attr_float_array = vec1[5] # 5D array of floats
    rt_attr_int8_array = vec2[3] # 3D array of small 8-bit integers
    # ...
}

source test1
{
    type = mysql

    sql_attr_int8_array = vec1[17] # 17D array of small 8-bit integers
    # ...
}
```

I am a bit confused about the type being used as MySQL in my file and as rt in the reference.
Need some help with the conversion. It would be highly appreciated if I can get a full guide for this.

Comment: Hide your password!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you won't have to change anything in index/source sections of your config.

> type being used as MySQL in my file and as rt in the reference

Note in your config `type=mysql` is for `source` while the in the example `type=rt` is for index. Those are 2 different things. `index` of `type=plain` (or not `type` since that's a default) can index from `source` if you specify `source = ...` in the index. Index of `type=rt` is a real-time index. Read the manual about the differences.